# Post from SQL intro HTML for dummies

Tags: datatable

I am working on a project that it's a bit over my basic level of web development I am not able to understand how to get specific data from my SQL and show it follow by a button that will show the entire data of the specific row a small example how it has to look on my html its: 
Name. Postcode telephone (button view more ).
And the next row will be the same. Hope this it understandable I can't wait for an answer.

Comment: Which database you use, which programming language you use, what have you tried so far? People here want you to help but you can't just come here and wait to someone done your's homework or something like that... And if you can't wait for answer than simply pay someone to do that for you and set him a deadline...

Comment: my database its like this::::::: echo 'succes';
$id = $_POST["id"];
$first_name = $_POST["first_name"]; // Since method=”post” in the form
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
$telephone = $_POST["abcd"];
$comments = $_POST["comments"];

Comment: please you have edit button in bottom left corner of your question so edit your question it's much better option then to add comment. it will be more readable. Also i suggest you to add tag's for php and tag for database you use is it ms sql, mysql, etc. so more people will se your question, and which is more importante it will see people who work with that programming languages

Comment: ok i am unable to explain what i am trying to do so as soon as you have reed this i will delete it and keep searching (i am traing to get from database the exact values and being posted on the right place i just need a code for ex: sql=get from abc value "n" post to html and whatever i have to add on html to show it to me  )thx

Comment: something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo_table)... and you want to add button at the end of each row

Comment: Yes now I have understand how I post and get and show on html but I steal don't know how to tell pho where exactly to place the details on the page EX I have a <table align=centre> and inside the table I use <td aligned left or right > to place I don't know anything , in html do I use a value or id or something to tell php where to place the request from SQL

Comment: well instead to echo table you create variable $myTable or something like that and in than in your <td aligned left or right>$myTable</td> and you will have table in your table... and one more thing when you change echo with $myTable do this in first $myTable = "<table>..." and on every other place you have to put dot (.) before equal sign like $myTable .= " your html code etc..."

Comment: now i got it yeyyyyy thx a loot

Comment: you're welcome :) I'm glad that i could help. I  will post answer down here so you can mark it as solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of your question here is how you take data from database with php and show it on the page. [Read this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo_table) Also there are a several way to do that, more example you can [find here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) if you interested...

For second part of your question to show data on specific location on your page, you should't just **echo** data instead of that place your code in variable something like this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     $myTable = "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $myTable .= "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "</td></tr>";
     }
     $myTable .= "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}
```

end then in your page i figured out it's organized as larger table just place variable $myTable where you want to be. Something like

```
<td class="">$myTable</td>
```

GL!

**P.S.** note that when you continue string for my table you have .= (dot equal) sign if you miss it it won't work as you expect..